# How to make a two condition search field with strict search? and how to hide search result before search

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I want to make a table with two 2 column, one column is about name and other column is number.
And people who going to search must field both exact match.
And by default the table is displaying all the content, I want it always hide until people do strict search.

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/24000cc278.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
    <table
    id="mytable"
    data-toggle="table"
    data-pagination="true"
    data-strict-search="true"
    data-search="true"
    data-search-on-enter-key="true"
    data-show-search-button="true"
    data-search-text="Your Search Query">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php if( have_rows('table_title') ): ?>
                    <?php $i=0; while ( have_rows('table_title') ) : the_row(); ?>
                        <?php
                        $title = get_sub_field('title');
                        ?>
                    <th><?php echo $title;?></th>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="searchable">
            <?php if( have_rows('table') ): ?>
                <?php $i=0; while ( have_rows('table') ) : the_row(); ?>
                    <?php
                    $colmun1 = get_sub_field('col-1');
                    $colmun2 = get_sub_field('col-2');
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $colmun1;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $colmun2;?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "must field both exact match" ?
Do you mean they have to fill both search inputs (filter-control extension) with the exact value of the columns ?
Or do you mean the search should ignore e.g. 'house' if you search 'hou' and only match 'hou' ?